# How to revert the Workflow Process for the Bundle as normal user in Anguilla?

Tags: cme, workflow

When I tried to revert the Workflow Process for the Bundle as a normal user through below code in Anguilla, It's showing the error as "You doesn't have enough permissions to do that".

```
 process.deleteItem();
```

Can you please let me know how to revert the workflow process for the bundle as normal user in Anguilla.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow Processes can only be deleted/cancelled/reverted by users with Workflow Management Rights in the Publication where the workflow runs. That is a Business Rule that can't be bypassed other than by impersonating another user (or elevating privileges if you're using SDL Web 8).

Why do you have this requirement? Wouldn't it be an option to provide Workflow Management Rights to the users that can revert workflow processes?